# "View Page Source" via command line

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I would like to download the content that I get from the "view page source" e.g. in Chromium or Firefox in some automated way (python or bash..).

wget, curl or alike...

I do not get the right data from the website downloaded if i e.g. use:

> curl https://www.google.com/search?foo&baa

Chromium too seems to have a problem in context with selenium now that it is snap by default. (I start to hate snap the more i know about it.)

Answer (score 0):

you can for example make file:

`touch gnu_source`

and then curl link and append it to gnu_souce:

`curl https://www.gnu.org/ >> gnu_source`

Comment: this for some reason does not contain the same information in my case...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? `curl` is getting source every time and on every site i used

Comment: I would like to get most recent market data, because I want to control things in my (and other) homes, to reduce the bills. So i go to the site that publishes the price data (according to the contract with the electricity retailer).
Now the site that i want to use the data from is:
https://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data?market_area=DE&trading_date=&delivery_date=2022-10-16&underlying_year=&modality=Continuous&sub_modality=&technology=&product=15&data_mode=graph&period=&production_period=

but it does not contain the data of that graph if i curl or wget it... 
"view page source" does

Comment: Did you checked `robots.txt`, maybe that data (price) is Disallowed for scraping?

Comment: Yes, but i do not now, what exactly refers to the data that I am looking at.

Secondly, how can the contents of 'robots.txt' make any difference? I CAN download the data and view it in the browser. I just need to get this automated.
Isn't the purpose of robots.txt just to direct bots towards real content, instead of them downloading the whole site?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is crazy simple... use quotation marks!

```
curl "https://www.google.com/search?foo&baa"
```

instead of

```
curl https://www.google.com/search?foo&baa
```

Many websites e.g. use a `&` to separate variables, bash however will interpret this as a command terminator, therefore misinterpreting as multiple commands. Putting the whole url under quotation allows bash to interpret correctly as one url to be passed on to curl.

Comment: `curl` has no way of knowing if you used quotations or not; their presence does, however, change how the shell parses your URL _before_ curl is started.

Comment: So, to give you a concrete example: `curl https://example.com/foo?bar=baz&qux=meh` will parsed by a shell as two separate commands when you run it without quotes: The first command is `curl https://example.com/foo?bar=baz` (which, being terminated with a `&`, the shell treats itself as instructed to run in the background); and the second command is `qux=meh`, which the shell in this situation would run as an assignment instructing it to create a variable named `qux`.

Comment: So it's not a curl problem, or ever anything curl can tell is happening at all! As far as curl can tell, `https://example.com/foo?bar=baz` is a perfectly valid URL; how was it supposed to know what you really wanted was `https://example.com/foo?bar=baz&qux=meh`?

Comment: BTW, if your question had provided a [mre] that _showed_ you using curl without quotes (while invoking a URL with a `&` or other character the shell is prone to parse in an unexpected way), it would have been answerable! Right now only you had the information that this was what you were actually doing, so _nobody but you could have possibly answered this question_ as it was asked.

Comment: Thx a lot for the explaination!

Comment: This is my first time here, so I will try to provide more detailed information the next time.

Comment: When you have a chance, think about editing the question so it shows all the essential elements of the problem, and editing the answer with some explanation (now that you know that explanation). The larger goal here is to build a knowledge base of common problems and their solutions, so the value of a question and answer pair doesn't end after the first person to ask the question has an answer.